# How to find a specific text is available in .txt file using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I want to write a PowerShell script where I will give two string values as parameters, It should check the .txt file and should tell whether the strings are available or not in the given file. For example, if I have a list of employees details. I will give the emp_id and emp_name as input. If the name and id exist in that .txt file it should print that. If not it should print the else statement.

```
Function Empdetails {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
    param (   
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$empid,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$empname)   
        $path = Get-Content C:\empdetails.txt | Where-Object {$_ -like '*name*'}
    if ($path -eq $true) {
        Write-Host "Found"  
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "Not Found"
    }
}
```

I tried the above code, But it is working. Could you please help me to figure it out?

Comment: `"$_ -like '*$empname*'"` you mean? Should both values from the input be found or is either one enough? If a search criterum is found, the result from such a test will not be a Boolean ($true or $false) value.. `Get-Content` returns an array of all lines in the text file. The `Where-Object` tries to filter the line(s) that match your test inside the brackets and returns those matched string(s). Why use a variable name `$path` there, as it has nothing to do with a file path..

Comment: please add a sanitized sample of your input file. testing code that does what you want without any sample text to test against is ... unreliable. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

You have two parameters but you are not using them in your function, since it's not clear which parameter should be used for the file path and which for the word you're searching for in the file, I have changed the parameter names for something more explanatory.

Also note, the result of below expression will be either an array of *strings*, a single *string* or `$null`:

```
$path = ... | Where-Object {$_ -like '*name*'}
```

Hence, your `if` condition `if ($path -eq $true)` can **never** be met unless `$path` has assigned the literal string **True**. If, however, you change the order of the condition to `$true -eq $path`, then the condition can be met and will be `$true` as long as `$path` is not `$null` / *empty string*.

```
$content = 'something'
$content -eq $true # => False
$true -eq $content # => True

$content = 'True'
$content -eq $true # => True
$true -eq $content # => True
```

From [equality operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#equality-operators):

> The equality operator can compare objects of different types. It is important to understand that the value is on the right-hand side of the comparison can be converted to the type of the left-hand side value for comparison.

```
Function Empdetails {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$FilePath,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$WordToSearch
    )

    $content = Get-Content $FilePath | Where-Object {$_ -like "*$wordToSearch*"}

    if ($content) {
        # if `$content` is populated, use return to end the function here
        return Write-Host "Found"
    }
    Write-Host "Not Found"
}

Empdetails -FilePath ./path/to/file.ext -WordToSearch somekeyword
```